# Error when translating Random Forest model to rules using iTrees package

Tags: r, random-forest

This is a bit of an obscure one but I am hoping somebody can help. I am having trouble translating a Random Forest model into rules using the iTrees package:

The example below produces the error:
Error in vector("list", rf$ntree) : invalid 'length' argument

```
require(inTrees)

require(caret)
require(RRF)

x1 <- read.table(header=T, text="B  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7  P8  P9  P10 P11 P12 P13 Target
B1  a   a   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   9
                 B2 a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   j   16
                 B3 a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   13
                 B4 b   i   b   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   b   10
                 B5 a   f   a   f   f   f   f   f   f   f   f   f   a   8
                 B6 a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   8
                 B7 b   b   b   h   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   b   29
                 B8 e   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   j   20
                 B9 a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   14
                 B10    a   a   g   a   a   j   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   22
                 B11    a   h   a   h   h   h   h   h   h   h   h   h   a   25
                 B12    a   f   a   f   f   f   f   f   f   f   f   f   j   11
                 B13    a   b   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   18
                 B14    a   a   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   13
                 B15    b   g   b   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   i   j   21
                 B16    a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   17
                 B17    d   j   d   j   j   j   j   j   j   j   j   j   d   18
                 B18    a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   18
                 B19    a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   j   14
                 B20    a   g   a   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   g   a   13
                 ")

#View(x1)

#Partition
set.seed(3456)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(x1$`Target`, p = .8, 
                                  list = FALSE, 
                                  times = 1)

dataTrain <- x1[ trainIndex,]
dataTest  <- x1[-trainIndex,]


# Model with caret
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  ## repeated ten times
  repeats = 10,
  savePredictions = "all"
)

set.seed(825)
RFFit1 <- train(Target ~ ., dataTrain, 
                method = "RRF",
                metric = "RMSE",
                trControl = fitControl,
                verbose = FALSE
)

RFpred1 <- predict(RFFit1, dataTest, type = "raw")


#Translate model to list
treeList <- RF2List(RFFit1)
```

When I examine the output of the mdoel there doesnt seem to be a column called rf$ntree. Im wondering if there is anything to do with the fact that I am using cross validation with caret? If so is there a way of using cross validation and producing an RRF object so that it can be interpreted by RF2List?

Any help greatly appreciated as always

Will.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but `inTrees` (for `RF2List`) and `ranger` are two nonstandard packages and `RF2List` needs a random forest object. Do you have some reason (example) do believe that `RF2List` is even suppose to work with the output of `ranger`? The example in `?RF2List` uses `RRF`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. You could be on to something as when I run the standalone model with RRF it works. But the caret still fails with the same message. I previously successfully built rules based on a ranger model as it is also a random forest.

Comment: My point was simply that accepting "random forest objects" is very vague; typically it means that the same package has a function for that or that somewhere in the documentation a certain other package is mentioned. Me and you also can implement a random forest algorithm by hand, but without extra efforts there is no way that `RF2List` would accept output from our functions. Perhaps I'm wrong, I'm not familiar with neither `ranger` for `inTrees`.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated the question in order to provide clarity.